# Waiting for a method to return true

Tags: java

I'm attempting to make a launcher that will update a piece of program I'm making, but I have ran into some issues. I want the launcher to be light weight, so I have been using `timer.schedule(this, 0, checkVersionTime);` to make it check for a new version every now and then. (an exact time isn't necessary. The default is 10 sec).

The problem is this code

```
if(!isOutdated(lastModified, sFile))
    continue;

if(scanner != null && !scanner.hasStopped())
    scanner.requestStop();

if((scanner == null || scanner.hasStopped())){
    downloadList.add(new QueuedFile(sUrl, fileId, sFile, lastModified));
}
```

the scanner variable contains the other program, calling requestStop will close the program properly instead of force close it. When it does, It can take up to 10 sec before the launcher detects the program is closed, and begin with the update.

How can I make so after calling `requestStop()` that the launcher sits there and waits until the program have closed?

EDIT:
This is how the other program is started, I'm not sure it counts as a 2nd JVM

```
public boolean load(File file){
    try{
        //Setup and load the class
        URL[] urls = {file.toURI().toURL()};
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
        Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("scanner.Scanner");
        scannerObject = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Thread.join?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join())

Comment: @immibis Sorry, bad topic name. I don't have access to the 2nd's program's thread.

Comment: @Yemto: When you say "2nd program", do you mean that you're actually waiting for a different JVM process to exit ? If not, you can get the list of all the running threads in the current JVM by calling `Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet()`, and filter out the current thread: `Thread.currentThread()`.

Comment: How did you start the program? `Process` has a `waitFor` method which works the same way as `Thread.join`.

Comment: @immibis I added the code I star the second program with.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the launcher as a [shutdown hook](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) and this will make it execute when the main app will exit (unless it is killed with the actual KILL signal).